# Unable to install a Python package

Tags: python

Whenever I try to install the SpeechRecognition package within my Python environment it keeps telling me `You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 20.3.3 is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.`, However, when I check the pip version I can see that it's on the latest version. The package doesn't install and continues to show this message.

Also just an off question, what does the `-m` wildcard do for the `pip install` command?

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance,
-Yaseen

Comment: Is that actually preventing something from working? Normally that's just a warning.

Comment: I had to install it by going into powershell and doing it manually, but I've had other packages install fine within my interpretor before, just don't understand why this package isn't installing like the other packages that my interpretor installed without any problem.

Comment: `-m` is not a "wildcard", its a (command-line) argument. Its also not being applied to `pip`, its being passed to `python`, and it tells python to invoke the specified module, in this case `pip`

Comment: Do you uses Anaconda as package manager? Are you sure you're picking up the right python and pip? Check those paths and tell us what they are?

Comment: Yes my PYTHONPATH and regular PATH is set to my virtual env, strangely it only seems to be with this package

Comment: No but also tell us the path to `pip`? Show us the path to pip and python that you're picking up. You might be picking up a stray old pip version.

Comment: Also instead of saying *"trying to install the SpeechRecognition package within my Python environment"*, edit in the exact command line you use. (Did you use pip, 'python -m pip ...', conda install, Anaconda's GUI installer, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade the pip using this command:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```